# Create an image/bitmap object in C# made of the sum of small images

Tags: c#, bitmap, drawrectangle

Im coding this game in c# (https://www.google.cz/search?q=vlacek+hra&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDtY7BosrTAhUDGZoKHfL5DuIQ_AUICCgB&biw=1280&bih=624#imgrc=dnnr33z9bcaNnM:), which is a czech version of the Snake, using Windows Forms and System.Drawing.

So far the behavior and functioning is not a problem, the doubt i have and i cannot answer is, is it possible to create and image, bitmap, graphic, rectangle or any of those objects that could work, made of the sum of small images. Being specific, each level of the game have the normal walls, plus the specific level walls, so how can i draw that wall or create an image or bitmap, made of the repetition of one image.

The problem is that i need to create the wall, from the sum of this small image https://github.com/PabloRodriz/Vlacek-hra-Train-Game-/blob/master/Snake%20Game/Images/wall.gif (here is where all the code i will be updating is) , which will go "inside" a rectangle object (Graphics.DrawImage(Image, Rectangle), cause i need the rectangles to check the collision with walls and the body of the train.

So how i draw the whole wall with just that image. A loop and draw multiple times the same image? Can i store all of that in a single image?

Comment: Paste your code here

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're using WinForms here. If this is WPF instead, let us know.

Instead of drawing bitmaps, why don't you use vector methods available within GDI+? You should store each level's walls configuration in memory (xml/whatever). These would probably all be sets of line segments (x1,y1 to x2,y2). Then upon invalidation, you can read current level's walls data and draw them within `Paint` event using `e.Graphics.DrawLine()` or `e.Graphics.DrawRectangle()` etc.

Make sure you `Invalidate()` your form/control in the timer you're using to create game frames. Many people make the mistake of creating the `Graphics` object within the timer event, causing severe impact on game responsiveness.

Your walls data should look something like this:

```
class Wall
{
  public Point Start {get; set;}
  public Point End {get; set;}
}
```

and the Level class would be something like

```
class Level
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public List<Wall> Walls {get; set;}
}
```

You can implement a collision detector within the `Wall` class, which would simply be a function that checks whether the snake's head (x,y) lies on that line segment.

Comment: Im definitely going to try this. In order to detect collisions i use the method  IntersectsWith, because the snake parts are rectangles, and the walls were rectangles also.

Comment: @PabloRodriz: Two things: Unless your walls have varying thickness at different points, you should represent them with x1,y1 and x2,y2 (with an optional thickness property maybe). Secondly, understand that the only part of the snake that can collide with a wall is its head. The snake should be represented with a `List<Point>` and you should always check the first point of this list (the head of the snake) against the walls dimensions. Even if u decide to represent your walls with rectangles instead of lines, you should use `Rectangle.Contains(Point)` for intersection.